# How to convert bmp to png and keep alpha channel?

Tags: image, bitmap, imagemagick, alpha

I have a p.bmp file, it look like has a alpha channel. so i try to convert it to png file by use imagemagick.

But whatever i try, the png file cannot keep the alpha channel:

#### [The p.bmp file:](https://web.archive.org/web/20131129213051/http://wonder.meteor.com/p.bmp)

[image: p.bmp]

#### [convert p.bmp p.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARiBg.png)

[image: p.png]
<sub>(source: [meteor.com](http://wonder.meteor.com/p.png))</sub>

#### [convert p.bmp png24:p24.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfOj9.png)

[image: p24.png]
<sub>(source: [meteor.com](http://wonder.meteor.com/p24.png))</sub>

#### [convert p.bmp png32:p32.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAyW2.png)

[image: p32.png]
<sub>(source: [meteor.com](http://wonder.meteor.com/p32.png))</sub>

Could anyone help me to find the alpha data in the p.bmp file, and convert it to png file?

Comment: Can you add a link to your bmp?

Comment: I add the link to my images :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You discovered a bug in ImageMagick. This will be fixed in ImageMagick 6.8.7-9. I am one of the developers for ImageMagick and I just committed the fix to our SVN repository (http://trac.imagemagick.org/changeset/13867).